# Testing deezer application and is returned: "You must enter a valid redirect uri"

Tags: javascript, deezer

I'm testing a application using deezer javascript SDK, but when I try to login page I receive a "You must enter a valid redirect uri".

Using:

```
 DZ.init({
    appId: '000000',
    channelUrl: 'http://localhost:13350/channel/channel.html',
    player: {
        onload: function (response) {
            alert('register: DZ.player is ready');
        }
    }
});
```

And for login:

```
DZ.login(function (response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        DZ.api('/user/me', function (response) {
            alert('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
        });
    } else {
        alert('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
    }
}, { perms: 'basic_access,email' });
```

So, what I need to do for test the application? The channelUrl is setted exactly this way in Application Domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in My apps in developers.deezer.com.

It's only necessary configure Application Domain as localhost:13350.

Answer (score 0):

This error is displayed when the application domain you filled is different than the domain of your host. Did you check this?